# Sending UTC dates from Javascript to MVC

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc

I have an Angular front end that sends back JSON to an MVC back end.  All dates are converted in JS, using `moment()` to ISO format before being sent i.e. `StartDate: 2015-02-17T15:06:12.180Z`

For some reason MVC does not treat these as being in UTC and will convert them to local time.  One thing I do use though is MVC's ability to automatically parse JSON into POCOs.  My method signature is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddSchedule(Schedule schedule)
```

How can I make MVC treat dates properly?

Comment: As in the dates you pass back with JSON are already utc, and when parsed into C# they are converted to local server time?

Comment: I have a similar issue although the dates are shown to be UTC.  The issue is when they get saved to the database its the UTC time that's stored.  For DOB pickers this is a pain because in summer time a day can be taken off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't the behaviour I would expect. Usually when I pass JSON containing dates to c#, they are not changed to local times. Is there code in your Schedule parameter-less constructor that could be affecting the dates?

If not you might have to use the C# ToUniversalTime() function on your dates after they are passed into your controller.

Comment: I have no constructors affecting it.  I am now using the `ToUniversalTime` function in order to convert them back.